# Can somebody help me set up simple DB replication in MariaDB?

Tags: replication, mariadb

I need DB replication between one master and one slave, but I've stumbled into problems literally every step of the way. ChatGPT has been a big help, but now I'm stumped and cannot get out of this one no matter how I re-word the question.

This is the core error I get during MariaDB startup on the slave:

```
[ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master
'replication_user@10.0.0.2:3306' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries:
100000  message: Access denied for user 'replication_user'@'the_slave'
(using password: YES), Internal MariaDB error code: 1045
```

*(Note: 10.0.0.2 is the master server IP)*

I tried connecting to the master using the mysql command as user replication_user and was successful. I can see the databases I'm supposed to have access to with `SHOW DATABASES;`. It's just the damn replication permission that's not working.

Moreover, when I tried to stop the slave so I could start over and re-set all master parameters, I get this completely unhelpful error:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> stop slave;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to server during query
```

And then I'm stuck connected to a supposedly dead server for the rest of the session even though the mariadb process is still `active (running)`:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> stop slave;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): Server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: Can't connect to the server
```

I'm basically stuck now as I can't even undo what I already did. What the hell did I do wrong here, guys? Version mismatch perhaps? I'm using the latest versions available in each respective distro:

MASTER: `mysql  Ver 8.0.35 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`

SLAVE: `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.4-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** Grants on the master:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'replication_user'@'the_slave';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replication_user@the_slave                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO `replication_user`@`the_slave`      |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `my_db`.* TO `replication_user`@`the_slave` |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why do you need/want the master and slave running in different distros?

Comment: I've already sacrificed enough by making sure the distros are at least all Debian-based. I gave up trying to get my CentOS-based systems to play ball. I figured that would be enough? Isn't Linux Linux? I shouldn't need to match the exact distros if I'm using classic standard software like MySQL and postfix/dovecot. Or maybe things have changed...?

As for the actual reason - the master is a desktop machine and all the slaves are VPSs. If I had to switch distros every time something didn't work, I'd have to compartmentalize everything into virtual machines which is wasted RAM when avoidable.

Comment: Yes, it should all be distro agnositic. I see you have a MySQL master. Its default authentication plugin may not be supported by mariadb. Try:  `alter user 'replication_user'@'the_slave' identified with mysql_native_password BY 'thepassword'`. `stop slave` -> connection gone away looks like MariaDB crashing. Can you look at the error log and report a [bug[(https://jira.mariadb.org/). Note MariaDB may not support all MySQL replication messages.